# Error Installing RestSharp in a Xamarin iOS app - Could Not Install Package

Tags: xamarin, restsharp

Trying to add package RestSharp to Xamarin iOS app.  Receive error:

```
Could not install package 'RestSharp 105.0.1'.  
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'Xamarin.iOS, Version=v1.0' but the package does not contain any assemblies 
compatible with the framework.
```

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.iOS Unified project?

Answer (score 2):

The RestSharp NuGet package from NuGet.org does not contain any assemblies that are compatible with iOS.

There is a [RestSharp component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp) available from Xamarin's component store which you could use instead.

Another option is to find a different NuGet package that provides a portable class library. There are a few portable versions of RestSharp available on NuGet.org